# How is the loopback device traffic allowed?

Tags: command-line, security, iptables, loop-device

How can I allow the traffic to be sent on the loopback device (lo)? What is the iptables command for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your question, I presume that you either have default `xtables` policies of `DROP` on your chains, or you have explicit `DROP`/`REJECT` rules near the end of your chains. Any `ACCEPT` rules must come before these.

Rule examples:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT # accept any traffic coming from lo.
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT # accept any traffic sent to lo.
```

If you want to play around with testing this, here is a dump to load into iptables-restore. I've explicitly added the -s/-d 127.0.0.1 so you can see how what is normally being matched on (you could match `-d` in `OUTPUT` and `-s` in `INPUT` if you wanted). Also, I've used non-standard ICMP reject responses, so you can tell which rule matched your patches easily. If you change the order of these rules (they accept for now), you can trigger the rejections. You can also try adding another IP like `127.0.0.2/8` to your loopback interface and testing between that IP and the normal `127.0.0.1/8` IP (you'll want to explicitly specify a source IP in `ping`).

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.20 on Sat Dec  7 23:10:52 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -o lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-prohibited
COMMIT
```

The `FORWARD` chain is seldom used with loopback interfaces, unless you're doing things with tunneling traffic (and you might bind to loopback locally).

Answer (score 2):

A rule of `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` would allow any traffic sent over lo. But due to how `Xtables` works, you need to make sure the rule comes before any rules that would deny a matching packet for it to work.